# search query very slow how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing

Ive got a search query that uses some joins to search in different correlating tables. But recently I've added about 3000 contacts to the contactpersonen table. And it got really slow.

Tables are these:
debiteuren : 1445 entries
contactpersonen: 3711 entries 
debiteuren_toegang: 3008 entries

```
    SELECT 
    contactpersonen.id,
    contactpersonen.voornaam,
    contactpersonen.achternaam,
    debiteuren.bedrijfsnaam,
    debiteuren.id as debid
FROM
    debiteuren
        LEFT JOIN
    contactpersonen ON contactpersonen.bedrijf = debiteuren.id
        LEFT JOIN
    debiteuren_toegang ON debiteuren_toegang.bedrijf = debiteuren.id
WHERE
    (contactpersonen.voornaam LIKE '%henk%'
        OR contactpersonen.achternaam LIKE '%henk%'
        OR debiteuren.id LIKE '%henk%'
        OR debiteuren.bedrijfsnaam LIKE '%henk%'
        OR contactpersonen.id LIKE '%henk%')
        AND debiteuren_toegang.website = 'web1'
LIMIT 10
```

When I remove the part that searches trough `contactpersonen.voornaam LIKE '%henk%' OR contactpersonen.achternaam LIKE '%henk%'` The query is really fast again.

Ive added an index in phpmyadmin on voornaam and achternaam, but that didnt help anything.

Any ideas on how to make this quicker? I don't think this is a lot of rows right? Queries last for even 5 seconds at times.

Thanks!

FULL QUERY EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
| id | select_type |       table        |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |                  ref                  | rows |    Extra    |  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | debiteuren_toegang | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 3008 | Using where |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | debiteuren         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | deb12311_1.debiteuren_toegang.bedrijf |    1 |             |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contactpersonen    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 4169 | Using where |  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
```

PARTIAL QUERY EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
| id | select_type |       table        |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |                  ref                  | rows |    Extra    |  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | debiteuren_toegang | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 3008 | Using where |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | debiteuren         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | deb12311_1.debiteuren_toegang.bedrijf |    1 | Using where |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contactpersonen    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                  | 4098 |             |  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Please, add `EXPLAIN` output for both cases

Comment: Done, they dont differ much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   ` SELECT 
    contactpersonen.id,
    contactpersonen.voornaam,
    contactpersonen.achternaam,
    debiteuren.bedrijfsnaam,
    debiteuren.id as debid
FROM
    debiteuren
        LEFT JOIN
    contactpersonen ON contactpersonen.bedrijf = debiteuren.id
        LEFT JOIN
    debiteuren_toegang ON debiteuren_toegang.bedrijf = debiteuren.id
WHERE
 debiteuren_toegang.website = 'web1'
        AND
   instr ( concat(contactpersonen.voornaam, contactpersonen.achternaam, debiteuren.id, debiteuren.bedrijfsnaam,contactpersonen.id) , 'henk'
        )>0

LIMIT 10`
```

Comment: It is significantly faster, but still 1.3 seconds.

Comment: The reason is you have two left joins. Just try looking at ur data if you can join these table in one subquery and use only one left join also check for index for the columns you used in your joins.

Comment: Also try adding indexed columns in where clause and limiting the records in select statement.

Comment: Krishna you mean indexes on the columns that are used to join? So the id's?

Comment: Yes if it is not a primary key then indexing on these column will definately show performance improvements..

Comment: Yes that did it! The primary id's are already indexed, but I didnt have debiteuren_toegang.bedrijf and contactpersonen.bedrijf indexed yet. Now its blazing fast again! Thanks a lot!